# What does pump down means in this solution?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

Problem text (from Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation"):

> **2.42** Let $E = \{1,\#\}$ and $Y = \{ w \mid w = t_1\#t_2\# ...... \#t_k \, \text{for $k \geq 0$, each $t_i \in 1^*$, and $t_i \neq t_j$ whenever $i \neq j$}\}$.
>
> Prove that $Y$ is not context free.

Solution:

> Consider  a string $1^p\#1^{p+1}\# ... \#1^{2p-1}\#1^{2p}\#1^{2p+1}\#
> > ... \#1^{3p}$ where $p$ is pumping length. While pumping there can be
> three possibilities :
>
> 1. If either v or y has a #. If so, then pump string 3 times. Let's say hash is in v s.t. $v = 1^m\#1^n$, then $v^3$ will be
>    $1^m\#1^n1^m\#1^n1^m\#1^n = 1^m\#1^{n+m}\#1^{n+m}\#1^n$. Otherwise #
>    will be in y, which can be shown similarly.
> 2. If # lies in $x, 
>    >      a$. $v$ lies in $1^j$ such that $j<2p$. if $|v| = 1$then pump up it twice, else if $|v| > 1$ then pump up it once. We must get $t_i$
>    which will be equal to some $t_j$.  I have considered to pump twice if
>    $|v| = 1$ because it may happen that $|y| \neq 0$. Think what am I
>    talking.
>    b. $y$ lies in $1^j$ such that $j \geq 2p$. if $|y| = 1$ then pump down it twice, else if $|y| > 1$ then pump down it once.
>    c. If one of the $v$ and $y$ is empty then pump other up or down once depending on where it lies i.e. $1^j$   $j$ is greater than $2p$
>    or other way.
> 3. If both $v$ and $v$ lies in same $1^j$, and $j \leq 2p$ then pump up it once. Else if $j > 2$p then pump down it once.

### My Question

I know that in pumping lemma if language $L$ is a CFL, then $w \in L = uvwxy$ and $uv^nwx^ny \in L$ for all $n\geq 0$.

How can I pump down it twice? I think it means $ n = -1$.

Comment: In the version of Sipser's book that I have (3rd edition), this is exercise 2.54 and no answer is provided. If yours is an older edition, consider the possibility of the solution having a "bug" and having been removed in later editions.

Comment: Do you also think it doesn’t add up?

Comment: You cannot choose $n=-1$ since $n$ has to be non-negative. It's probably a mistake.